# Combining multiple securities' Net Asset Value time-series into one total NAV series

Tags: equities, time-series, quant-trading-strategies, trading, simulations

I have a number of individual securities that each have a Net Asset Value (NAV) time-series.  For example:

```
              NAV1    NAV2    NAV3
30/10/2014  100.00  100.00  100.00
31/10/2014  100.09  100.34   99.20
03/11/2014  100.98   99.96   98.55
04/11/2014  100.76  100.94   99.55
05/11/2014   99.99  100.04   98.97
06/11/2014  100.41   99.54   99.90
07/11/2014   99.54   99.56  100.86
10/11/2014  100.44   99.36  100.39
11/11/2014  101.21   99.06  100.26
12/11/2014  100.99   99.87  100.72
13/11/2014  101.28  100.21  100.12
14/11/2014  101.57  100.73   99.54
```

Could someone let me know how I can combine the individual security NAVs into a total NAV time-series please?

Can I simply add the NAV's together for each date and divide by the number of securities eg:

```
              NAV1    NAV2    NAV3  combined NAV
30/10/2014  100.00  100.00  100.00        100.00
31/10/2014  100.09  100.34   99.20         99.88
03/11/2014  100.98   99.96   98.55         99.83
04/11/2014  100.76  100.94   99.55        100.42
05/11/2014   99.99  100.04   98.97         99.67
06/11/2014  100.41   99.54   99.90         99.95
07/11/2014   99.54   99.56  100.86         99.99
10/11/2014  100.44   99.36  100.39        100.06
11/11/2014  101.21   99.06  100.26        100.18
12/11/2014  100.99   99.87  100.72        100.53
13/11/2014  101.28  100.21  100.12        100.54
14/11/2014  101.57  100.73   99.54        100.61
```

or is there a more robust way to do it?  The purpose of the total NAV would be to compare different simulation results

Thanks

Comment: Yes the simple average is valid. Imagine you start off with $X and put X/3 into each asset, then at some future time you will have a total that is the sum of the new NAVs times by the allocations.